# My code works for 200,000 prime numbers but shows segmentation error(core dumped) when i try to run it for 2,000,000 numbers

Tags: gcc, g++, primes

'My code works for 200,000  prime numbers but shows segmentation error(core dumped) when i try to run it for 2,000,000 numbers'

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
long long n;
cin>>n;
long long prime[n];
for(long long i=0;i<=n;i++){
    prime[i]=1;
}
prime[0]=0;
prime[1]=0;
for(long long i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++){
for(long long j=2;i*j<=n;j++){
    prime[i*j]=0;
}
}
unsigned long long res=0;
for (long long i = 2; i <= n; ++i){
    if(prime[i]==1){
    res+=i;
    }
}
cout<<res;
}
```

Comment: `long long prime[n];` is a variable-length array and not supported by C++. Use a std::vector

Comment: You might be overflowing the stack with that large array.  I suggest allocating it on the heap, instead.

Comment: your array of size `n`. So last index is n-1.  But your index is <= n in your nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long long prime[n];` is a variable-length array and not supported by C++. Some compilers support it with a compiler extension. The memory is allocated on the stack and it's larger than the stack size. Use a `std::vector` to allocate the memory on the heap.

Don't access `prime[n]`. The last element is `prime[n-1]`.

Use `i * i <= n` instead of `i <= sqrt(n)`.

I recommend to use `std::int64_t` instead of `long long`. `long long` has at least 64 bits. `std::int64_t` has exactly 64 bits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::int64_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::int64_t> prime(n);
    for(std::int64_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        prime[i] = 1;
    }
    prime[0] = 0;
    prime[1] = 0;
    for(std::int64_t i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i){
        for(std::int64_t j = 2; i * j < n; ++j){
            prime[i * j] = 0;
        }
    }
    std::uint64_t res = 0;
    for (std::int64_t i = 2; i < n; ++i){
        if(prime[i] == 1){
            res += i;
        }
    }
    std::cout << res;
}
```